# Why is the moderator icon showing up in red

Tags: support, design, moderators

Just noticed that @Ryan has a red diamond instead of a black diamond for his moderator logo:

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Chrome 59 no repo.

Comment: This happens with chrome on mobile devices; not entirely sure why, but it's been this way as long as I can remember

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267504/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-in-android | https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223155/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-for-question-titles-in-the-ios-app

Comment: @Bob Strange...I have been using SO with Chrome on my Android phone for years and I have never seen this.

Comment: Ryan is no longer a diamond moderator. He was promoted. Now he's a ruby moderator.

Comment: @honk sounds more like a demotion to me :(

Comment: @Jon Well I never!  You're...in red!

Comment: @JonClements: AFAIK the value of a ruby can be higher than that of a diamond. Depends on the quality ;)

Comment: @honk oh - you weren't referring to the programming language!? :p

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unless I'm going mad.... I'm fairly sure the diamond has always shown as red on meta... but blue on main... But always black in a user's profile page...

Comment: It was red on StackOverflow (main) when I saw it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what colour do you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588331/simple-cross-tabulation-in-pandas)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is it on a mobile device? I've always seen red diamonds on Chrome (Android, Nexus 5). Check in Firefox, it's blue again.

Comment: @JonClements: Good one! I didn't get it ;)

Comment: Isn’t that just the emoji version of the diamond? Some browsers replace specific symbols with emojis.

Comment: @Xufox Yes. Chrome on Android autoconverts those unicode emojis into actual emojis. Which is why diamonds are seen as red. (I might be wrong, though)

Comment: @Jon I even see "here" in RED.

Comment: @BhargavRao I see diamonds as blue on main on desktop mode and mobile mode, while orangey here in mobile and red in desktop...

Comment: This is what I see on Chrome, https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AcTE.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/G92IO.png

Comment: *I see red people*

Comment: Ryan is a vampire for real?

Comment: Do you really have 27 tabs open on your phone?

Comment: @Daniel Yes; I have about 10 open with SO and some documentation stuff.  The other tabs are for learning Mandarin, my other peeve.  And some news and email.

Comment: Wait... those diamonds are supposed to be black? I use chrome at home and IE at work and have never seen anything *other* than red.

Comment: @Daniel: I have 57. I recently trimmed them down from 72.

Comment: It's _the dress_, SO style.

Answer (score 6):

Bottom line here is that we just insert an `&#9830;` (equivalent to `&diams;`) character there and your browser and operating system are responsible for how that actually ends up rendered. If your system doesn't do anything special with the character, it will be colored as set by the site, which is usually the same color as the text or link surrounding it but also sometimes just black.

[This page](https://emojipedia.org/black-diamond-suit/) shows how some different systems and browsers will render the character. (I use HTC, so diamonds look like playing cards when I view them on mobile.)